# How to send _SESSION Vars through email using PHP

Tags: php, email, session-variables

I am trying to troubleshoot a web app and I want to see various _SESSION vars so I am trying to send them via email.

I receive the email but it is empty and the session vars end up displaying at the top of the web page instead of coming through mail().

I have tried both `print_r($_SESSION)` and `var_dump($_SESSION)` -- neither of them work.

Here is my line of code:

```
mail('me@mydomain.com', 'Session Var Dump', '<pre>'.var_dump($_SESSION).'</pre>');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `print_r($_SESSION, true);` The second parameter makes it output a string you can use in variables, etc. It's useful when you can't use `var_dump`

```
mail('me@mydomain.com', 'Session Var Dump', print_r($_SESSION, true));
```

Comment: excellent and easiest answer to implement of the 3 offered at this time-- thanks @Machavity

Answer (score 3):

Capture the output of `var_dump` as a string:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
$result = ob_get_clean();
mail('me@mydomain.com', 'Session Var Dump', '<pre>'.$result.'</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump` and `print_r` print directly to `STDOUT`. If you want to use them in a string context, supply true to the second parameter of `print_r` or wrap `ob_get_clean` in an output buffer.

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
$session = ob_get_clean();
```

or

```
$session = print_r($_SESSION, true);
```